# Sign up detecting registred users php

Tags: php, sql, database, authentication

im working on a login/sign up system to my website 
i have this little issue where the app doesnt reconize if the user is already registred or if it s not

```
<?php  
// including $conn the connextion between database and the app from the dbh.php
include '../dbh.php';

$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

    $sql = "SELECT * from user WHERE userid=".$userid;
    $results = mysqli_query($conn , $sql);
    $useridcheck = $results->num_rows;

//if there is a registred username in the database same as $userid
    if($useridcheck > 0)
    {

        header('location: ../signupform.php?error=username');
        exit();
    }
// there is no match to $userid in the database so go ahaid and register this new user
    else{
        $sql ="INSERT INTO user(first,last,userid,email,pwd) 
        VALUES('$first','$last','$userid','$email','$pwd')";
        $results = mysqli_query($conn , $sql);
         header('location: ../index.php');

    }
```

the problem is in the `if ($useridcheck > 0)` 
when the operator is set to `= 1` it runs the first block and if it's set to `> 0` it runs the second block. i dont know what is the problem but im guessing it has to be with the variable `$useridcheck = $results->num_rows`

Comment: `$useridcheck = mysqli_num_rows($results);` and check

Comment: @Anant why? `$results->num_rows;` is valid. Ok, it's mixing object oriented with procedural, but it's still valid.

Comment: something else is causing your code to break and you need to check for errors as to why that is.

Comment: *"when the operator is set to = 1"* - You mean `== 1`

Comment: it doesnt work with mysqli_num_rows same results,

Comment: something else like what ? could it be related with  the database ?  or the input file  ?  shall i post the dbh ( database script and the input field ? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace:
$useridcheck = $results->num_rows;

With:
$useridcheck = mysqli_num_rows($results);

Comment: I don't see how that would make a difference.